# Java Clipboard Event Listener not working

Tags: java, swing, clipboard, event-listener

I am trying to implement clipboard change event listener and I really stuck. Can't find an working example of how to implement it or whatever I find is not complete or not working. So I am trying to implement a prototype of this functionality but it has a bug... So each time when the clipboard content changed I want to see a pop up menu

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner;
import java.awt.datatransfer.FlavorEvent;
import java.awt.datatransfer.FlavorListener;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class MyTextArea extends JFrame implements ClipboardOwner, FlavorListener{

    JTextArea textArea;
    Clipboard clip;
    public MyTextArea() 
    {
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        textArea =  new JTextArea(40, 40);


        clip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clip.setContents(clip.getContents(null), this); 
        clip.addFlavorListener(this);



        Container cp  = this.getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        cp.add(textArea);

    }

    @Override
    public void flavorsChanged(FlavorEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Flavour Changed","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


        clip.removeFlavorListener(this);
        clip.setContents(clip.getContents(null), this);
        clip.addFlavorListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void lostOwnership(Clipboard arg0, Transferable arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new MyTextArea();

        frame.setVisible (true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }



}
```

Does anyone how to make this code working properly?

Comment: What problems in particular are you having?  For the most part, this seems to work okay for me (there are some instances where it won't and this is listed in the documentation for the `FlavorListener`)

Comment: in above example, the popup window from flavorsChanged event pops up all the time, and if i kill the application, next time I run it, the pop up window doesn't appear at all, only after I start it after some time. I want that window to pop up only when the content of the clipboard changed.